# Детали наследования Python OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы, наследование

Недавно учу *ООП*, прошу прощения.

Наивный вопрос. Есть супер-класс, скажем:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Пишем дочерние классы `Man(Human)`, `Woman(Human)`.
Я хочу сохранить все, что уже определено в `Human.__init__()`,
но добавить, скажем для `Man self.job`, для `Woman self.beauty`

Так, разумеется, не работает:

```
class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        super().__init__(self, name, age)
        self.job = job
```

Я понимаю, что для 2-3 свойств все можно переписать.
Ну а если повторяется 10 свойств супер-класса, и только одно новое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему *"разумеется"* не работает? Очень даже работает.

```
class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self, name, age, job):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.job = job
```

Просто `self` не надо передавать при вызове.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

```
class Human:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__()
        
        #print(f'{args}') #
        self.name = args[0]
        self.age = args[1]
        

class Man(Human):
    def __init__(self, job, *args):
        super(Man, self).__init__(*args)
        
        self.job = job

       
class Woman(Human):
    def __init__(self, beauty, *args):
        super(Woman, self).__init__(*args)
        
        self.beauty = beauty
        
        
man = Man('пекарь', 'Вася', 22)
print(f'\nman = {man.name}, {man.age}, {man.job}')

woman = Woman('beauty 1', 'Маша', 20)
print(f'\nwoman = {woman.name}, {woman.age}, {woman.beauty}')
```